# BERT - Extract values from all layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, word-embedding, bert-language-model

i'm trying to get the "Word Embedding" from BERT.
I have already fine tuned the model for "Sentiment classification" and the model predict if a sentence is positive or negative.
But i need to extract values from all layers to get the featurized representation.

i have tried something like this

all_layers = model.get_all_encoder_layers()

but doesn't works

```
# Compute # train and warmup steps from batch size
num_train_steps = int(len(train_features) / BATCH_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_EPOCHS)
num_warmup_steps = int(num_train_steps * WARMUP_PROPORTION)

# Specify outpit directory and number of checkpoint steps to save
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    model_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
    save_summary_steps=SAVE_SUMMARY_STEPS,
    save_checkpoints_steps=SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS)

model_fn = model_fn_builder(
    num_labels=len(label_list),
    learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
    num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
    num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    config=run_config,
    params={"batch_size": BATCH_SIZE})

# Create an input function for training. drop_remainder = True for TPUs.
train_input_fn = bert.run_classifier.input_fn_builder(
    features=train_features,
    seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    is_training=True,
    drop_remainder=False)
```

i have to change the model_fn to get values from all layers of BERT?

Comment: Do you just want token embeddings? Have you tried `extract_features.py` script?

Comment: i want values from all layers

Comment: The script `extract_features.py`, allows you to select the layers. So, you can give 1-12 or 1-24, as you need.

Comment: with this script i can extract the precomputed pre-computed feature vectors,
but i need to extract feature vectors while make a prediction ( and then in the given context )

Comment: You can do that by providing a finetune checkpoint, that you use for your predictions.

Comment: You mean: provide a finetuned checkpoint to extract_features.py script?

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: thanks, then is the same use extract_features with a checkpoint or return layers value when make a prediction?

Comment: yes, for the 1st part of the sentence. However, I did not understand the 2nd part.

Comment: Can I post this as an answer?